# Nuget package not adding Framework Assembly references

Tags: wpf, reference, nuget, .net-assembly

I have a very simple test library and I want to pack it into a nuget package. It works fine. Dependencies are added. But Framework Assembly References aren't, so I added manually:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2012/06/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>TestDLL2</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <title>TestDLL2</title>
    <authors>Oscar Rodríguez</authors>
    <owners></owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Librería de Prueba OR-Apps.</description>
    <copyright>Copyright © 2023</copyright>
    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework=".NETFramework4.8">
        <dependency id="ini-parser" version="2.5.2" />
        <dependency id="InputSimulatorPlus" version="1.0.7" />
        <dependency id="WpfAnimatedGif" version="2.0.2" />
      </group>
    </dependencies>
    <frameworkAssemblies>
      <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="PresentationFramework.Classic" targetFramework=".NETFramework4.5" />
      <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="System.Deployment" targetFramework="" />
    </frameworkAssemblies>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

Main problem: when I install the package in a project, only some references are added, but not all. In the previous sample "PresentationFramework.Classic" is added but "System.Deployment" isn't.

I tried with different references but not luck. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working. I forced "targetFramework" with a content:

```
<frameworkAssemblies>
    <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="PresentationFramework.Classic" targetFramework=".NETFramework4.8" />
    <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="System.Deployment" targetFramework=".NETFramework4.8" />
</frameworkAssemblies>
```